# Liferay - Exporting User-Generated Content

Tags: export, liferay

We are currently evaluating Liferay for our non-profit organization, and there's one concern that I have not been able to find an answer for:

Is there a way to export the user-created content (e.g. blog posts, wiki articles, forum discussions) into a structured format (e.g. xml, excel)?

In case we need to move away from Liferay in the future, we'd like to know that we can at least salvage all of the content that the users have created.

Thanks in advance for the help!

AL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copying my answer from [the liferay forum](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/6709584) to the same question (there's more, but I didn't want to embrace the other answer(s) as mine here:

In addition to the LAR export already mentioned, Liferay provides a full API to access all your content where you can access it in any way you like - e.g. only articles, by page, users etc.

To take a look at the content creation part of that API (barely reading) you can look at sevencogs-hook (sourcecode available in svn) - this creates the full demo site through the API. Equivalent reading functionality is available, though not that readily available in a full-blown sample to easily point to.

The API is accessible through Java or Webservices.